# Docker with Mongo and Express

Tags: docker, dockerfile

First of all, give thanks for reading my question and try to help me and apologize for my English.

I'm trying to run a docker with a express server project and mongo, but build Dockerfile perfectly but I do:

`docker logs -f name`

and show next error:

`/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint-sh line 340: exec: npm not found`

And, I think that mongodb doesnt run

Why doesnt recognize npm if I add node?
How can run npm and launch mongo?
I'm using ubuntu 17.10

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Install Node 
FROM node:latest

# Install Mongo
FROM mongo:4.0.0-xenial

# Author
MAINTAINER MachineGun

# Create user Ubuntu 17.10 (64 bits)
RUN adduser --disabled-login dockeruser

# Work Directory
WORKDIR /home/expressserver

# Copy express project to docker
COPY expressserver expressserver

# Defaul user
USER dockeruser

# Config cointainer PORT:
# MongoDB listening on port: 27017
# Server listening on port: 8080
EXPOSE 27017 8080

# Exec MongoDB
CMD [mongo]

# Exec server with custom npm start 
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

Also, in app.js I use mongoose with next uri: `mongodb://localhost:27017/ExpressServer`, its ok?

```
mongoose.connection.openUri('mongodb://localhost:27017/ExpressServer', { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, res) => {

    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: Database not running on port 27017: \x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', 'offline');
        // console.log('throw err: ', err);
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Database running on port 27017: \x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', 'online');
});
```

Comment: Why don't put both commands in the same CMD line? `CMD ["mongo", "npm", "run", "start:dev"]`. Or also `CMD ["sh", "-c", "mongo; npm run start:dev"]` Have you tried it?

Comment: (a) In your Dockerfile you are building two images; one is an unmodified Node image, the second is the MongoDB image.  That's probably not what you want.  (b) In a Docker context `localhost` is almost always wrong; please look it up, and please replace the hard-coded connection string with an environment variable.

Comment: use a docker-compose rather than a dockerfile? You can then set up your node env in a seperate dockerfile should you need it?

Comment: thanks... is my first Dockerfile... Is possible have in same Dockerfile node, mongo and have in one docker my express project with node and mongo running??

Comment: yes use supervisord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem :D
Thanks a lot :D

Finally I used docker compose...

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  server: 
    container_name: expressserver
    build: ./ 
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - mongo

  mongo: 
    container_name: mongoDB
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mongodb:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod --port 27017
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:carbon

MAINTAINER MachineGun

RUN adduser --disabled-login dockeruser

WORKDIR /home/dockeruser

COPY expressserver expressserver

WORKDIR /home/dockeruser/expressserver

RUN npm install

USER dockeruser

EXPOSE 8080 27017
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And in my app.js to connect with mongoose:

```
const options = {
    autoIndex: false, // Don't build indexes
    reconnectTries: 30, // Retry up to 30 times
    reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconnect every 500ms
    poolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
    // If not connected, return errors immediately rather than waiting for reconnect
    bufferMaxEntries: 0
 };


// Database connection
const connectWithRetry = () => {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo/expressdb", options)
    .then(()=>{
        console.log('Database running on port 27017: \x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', 'online')
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
        console.log('MongoDB connection unsuccessful on port 27017: \x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', 'offline');
        console.log('Retry after 5 seconds.');
        setTimeout(connectWithRetry, 5000)
    });
}
connectWithRetry();
```